# Run flyspell when loading new buffer with custom dictionary

Tags: org-mode, flyspell

Sometimes it is possible to add commands to the start of an `org-mode` buffer to customize it.

I would like `flyspell` to run and stay active with `pt_PT` dictionary on a specific file whenever I open it. This is an org-mode file opened with emacs.

How can I do that?

Comment: See file-local variables and also `ispell-local-dictionary`:  "*If non-nil, the dictionary to be used for Ispell commands in this buffer. The value must be a string dictionary name, or nil, which means use the global setting in 'ispell-dictionary'. Dictionary names are defined in 'ispell-local-dictionary-alist' and 'ispell-dictionary-alist'.  Setting 'ispell-local-dictionary' to a value has the same effect as calling 'ispell-change-dictionary' with that value.  This variable is automatically set when defined in the file with either 'ispell-dictionary-keyword' or the Local Variable syntax.*"

Comment: See also `flyspell-default-dictionary`:  "*A string that is the name of the default dictionary. This is passed to the 'ispell-change-dictionary' when flyspell is started. If the variable 'ispell-local-dictionary' or 'ispell-dictionary' is non-nil when flyspell is started, the value of that variable is used instead of 'flyspell-default-dictionary' to select the default dictionary. Otherwise, if 'flyspell-default-dictionary' is nil, it means to use Ispell's ultimate default dictionary.*"